# How to Identify Publishers and Consumers using Red5 API

Tags: java, jsp, streaming, red5

```
public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params)
    {
            IClient client = conn.getClient();
            log.info( "app connect " + conn.getClient().getId() );
            client.setAttribute( "stamp", new Long( 0 ) );
        return true;
    }
```

This is the method which is being called every time Client is connected at my Custom Application in Red5 Server ,so is there a way to identify if a Client is Subscriber (Consumer ,Viewer) or Publisher (User which streams at my server).

Bests

Comment: Sure, you can send some identity params from your SWF application.

Comment: @Dmitry Polushkin so there's only way to find out is using Object[] params,i thought i can identify Publishers someway ,when they start publishing ,like an Interface Method publishedStarted(); than i can authenticate them and decide if i should allow or disallow them to start Publishing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disallow or allow publish or subscribe a user, you can use those methods inside appStart callback method:

- registerStreamPlaybackSecurity
- registerStreamPublishSecurity

For more, look to the:

http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.html

I'm using jRuby, and it's very easy to do so:

```
registerStreamPlaybackSecurity do |scope, name, start, len, flush|
  false # no playback allowed
end
registerStreamPublishSecurity do |scope, name, mode|
  rand(1) % 1 == 0 # publishing (recording) sometimes allowed, sometimes no
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i`ll marked you're answer as correct but im using Java instead and i`ll see in API what i can do with that stuff .