# How to authenticate a user in Red5 `fitcDemo` sample?

Tags: java, chat, red5

I'm trying to change the source code of the `fitcDemo` application for Red5 and make it somehow authenticate the username before letting it to connect to the server but I have no idea how to get started!
I mean I don't know which method will be called upon client connect and how to get the username from the client app.
I will bring the source code here so that someone might be able to help me.

```
package org.xyz;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.red5.server.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IClient;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.Red5;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IPendingServiceCall;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IPendingServiceCallback;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IServiceCapableConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IBroadcastStream;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IPlayItem;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IPlaylistSubscriberStream;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.IStreamAwareScopeHandler;
import org.red5.server.api.stream.ISubscriberStream;


public class Application extends ApplicationAdapter
  implements IPendingServiceCallback, IStreamAwareScopeHandler
{
  protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);

  public boolean appStart(IScope scope)
  {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params)
  {
    IServiceCapableConnection service = (IServiceCapableConnection)conn;
    log.info("Client connected {} conn {}");
    service.invoke("setId", new Object[] { conn.getClient().getId() }, this);
    return true;
  }

  public boolean appJoin(IClient client, IScope scope)
  {
    log.info("Client joined app {}");

    IConnection conn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    return true;
  }

  public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream)
  {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("stream broadcast start: {}");
    }
    IConnection current = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    for (Set<IConnection> connections : this.scope.getConnections())
      for (IConnection conn : connections) {
        if (conn.equals(current))
        {
          continue;
        }

        if ((conn instanceof IServiceCapableConnection)) {
          ((IServiceCapableConnection)conn).invoke("newStream", new Object[] { stream.getPublishedName() }, this);

          if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("sending notification to {}");
        }
      }
  }

  public void streamRecordStart(IBroadcastStream stream)
  {
  }

  public void streamBroadcastClose(IBroadcastStream stream)
  {
  }

  public void streamBroadcastStart(IBroadcastStream stream)
  {
  }

  public void streamPlaylistItemPlay(IPlaylistSubscriberStream stream, IPlayItem item, boolean isLive)
  {
  }

  public void streamPlaylistItemStop(IPlaylistSubscriberStream stream, IPlayItem item)
  {
  }

  public void streamPlaylistVODItemPause(IPlaylistSubscriberStream stream, IPlayItem item, int position)
  {
  }

  public void streamPlaylistVODItemResume(IPlaylistSubscriberStream stream, IPlayItem item, int position)
  {
  }

  public void streamPlaylistVODItemSeek(IPlaylistSubscriberStream stream, IPlayItem item, int position)
  {
  }

  public void streamSubscriberClose(ISubscriberStream stream)
  {
  }

  public void streamSubscriberStart(ISubscriberStream stream)
  {
  }

  public List<String> getStreams()
  {
    IConnection conn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();
    return getBroadcastStreamNames(conn.getScope());
  }

  public void resultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call)
  {
    log.info("Received result {} for {}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Red5 provides methods to do that:
[How to Identify Publishers and Consumers using Red5 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775239/how-to-identify-publishers-and-consumers-using-red5-api)
I needed to identify them differently using a database, so this was my approach.
Assuming that you are already connecting a database with user related tables in red5.
If not, the official tutorial is a good place to get started:
http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials:MySQL_and_Red5
Although the tutorial is for MySQL, you can use the appropriate JDBC driver for your database.

First you need to send a user ID from the client in the connect() of NetConnection in Flash using as3:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var userID:String = "foo";
nc.connect("rtmp://" + ipAddrOfRed5Server + "/fitcDemo", userID);
```

In Red5:

```
public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn , Object[] params )
{
    try { 
         String uID = (String)params[0];             
         //Run a query here to check if the user exists in the DB. 
             // If not, you can call rejectClient("Not an existing user!");
             // Once authenticated here, your normal logic follows
    }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Error handling User connect"); 
    }       
    return true;

}
```